# Pull data our of JSON with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file being stored in a static url, i would like to grab it and pull our the data objects.

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('https://s3.amazonaws.com/wallyball_production/comedy.json', function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        });

    });
  </script>
```

This isn't outputting anything?  I did it very quickly, not sure why I'm not seeing anything?

Comment: $.getJSON will return object and not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-domain AJAX calls require `jsonp` (or writing a proxy server-side script). As long as the remote-server is setup properly (I'd think Amazon would be) it's pretty easy with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/wallyball_production/comedy.json',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success  : function (data) {
        //$('#content').html(data);
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            //`data[i].something` will access the `something` property an index of the JSON returned
        }
    }
});
```

Note that you will get JSON in response so you will need to iterate through it before appending it to the DOM.

Here are docs for jQuery's `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: I was with you until I saw your `success` callback. Isn't the response a JSON object, not HTML?

Comment: @AymanSafadi Yup that's why I noted that Xtian's code needs to be altered to iterate through the JSON result.

Comment: Hmmm, i thought I'd get something with: console.log('data[i].name'); in the for loop but nothing????

Comment: @Xtian Start with `console.log(data)` in the first line of the `success` callback. Check-out the structure of the JSON, and proceed from there. My example is just a guess since I don't know the structure of the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy), your web application can not ever interact with content from another domain.

You need to either proxy the request through your webserver (which then contacts amazon and returns the result), or use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).